# Shadow only on the outside curve

Tags: android, android-canvas

I aim to create something similar to a pie chart, but I can't get shadowing quite right. I want the shadow to be just on the outside curve of each segment and not the lines leading to the center. Is there  a way I can achieve that other than writing custom function similar to `paint.setShadowLayer()` ?
This is what I have so far:

```
        float mStart = 0;
        RectF mOvals = new RectF(mWidth / 15 + mGraphParams.leftMargin, mHeight / 15 + mGraphParams.topMargin,
                mWidth - mWidth / 15 - mGraphParams.rightMargin, mHeight - mHeight / 15 - mGraphParams.bottomMargin);
        float max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            max = max + data.get(i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            if (shadow) {
                paint.setShadowLayer(shadowRadius, shadowDx, shadowDy, this.pieColors.get(i));
            }
            float mSweep = (float) 360 * ((float) data.get(i) / max);
            paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
            paint.setColor(this.pieColors.get(i));
            canvas.drawArc(mOvals, mStart, mSweep, true, paint);

            mStart = mStart + mSweep;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not doable.

You have to override `setShadowLayer()`.

Sorry